# Spring GraphQL projection throws no bean resolver exception

Tags: spring-graphql

I have a Spring Boot application with Spring for GraphQL library and I need to modify the returned object. So I created and registered a projection class referring to my bean method:

```
public interface MyEntityProjection {

    @Value("#{@myBean.getName()}")
    public String getName();
}
```

But this results in `org.springframework.expression.spel.SpelEvaluationException: EL1057E: No bean resolver registered in the context to resolve access to bean 'myBean'` when the query is run. Probably a bean resolver needs to be registered somehow but there is no info in the documentation https://docs.spring.io/spring-graphql/docs/1.0.0-SNAPSHOT/reference/html/

Simple application illustrating my problem:  https://github.com/omichal/spring-graphq-no-bean-resolver

Answer (score 0):

This is a very opinionated behaviour from the framework itself unfortunately.
You have to prepend your spel with *target*.
In your case it will be:

```
@Value("#{target.name}")
```

By default the framework will call the original bean getName method - you don't need to put the get.

Comment: But that does not imply we can't call its method using 
#{@target.getName()}